# react native TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-navigation

I am using the `FacebookAuthProvider` by firebase to login my users from my platform.

I'm using react native in expo with firestore and it was working fine till I tried to add in some checks to redirect users to the correct screens after login. There are two different roles (*administrators* and *users*) which have to be separate right after the login.

```
if (/* user is administrator */) {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Admin');
} else {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
}
```

After adding this method to separate users by there roles, I got this error:

> react native TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Later I will add some more details (*log files etc. as soon as I've learned how to grep them from my locale machine*).

For better understanding I put my whole code here (*sorry for the bad indentations which lesses the readability*):

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const firebaseUser = '';
const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');

async handleFacebookButton() {

const { type, token,  } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, {
  permissions: ['public_profile', 'email']
});
if (type === 'success') {
  //Firebase credential is created with the Facebook access token.
  const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
  auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
  .then(function(userCredential) {
    newUserCheck = userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
    console.log('newUserCheck = ', newUserCheck)
  });
  this.setState({loggedIn: "You are signed in"})
  this.setState({signedIn: true})
  console.log('you are signed in');


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {

  firebaseUser = {name: user.displayName, uid: user.uid, email: user.email}
  console.log(firebaseUser.name, ' and ',  firebaseUser.uid);

    var existingRef = usersRef.doc(firebaseUser.uid);
    existingRef.get().then(function(documentSnapshot) {
      // check if user is registered
        if(documentSnapshot) {
          data = documentSnapshot.data();
          console.log('existing user exists!!');
            // check if user is an administrator
            if (data.administrator == true) {
                console.log('existing administrator exists!!');

                this.props.navigation.navigate('Admin');
              } else { this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
                }
        }
    });

    (error => {   
      console.log('user not accessed: ', error);
    });

    //User is not yet in firebase database and needs to be saved
    // double check that user is a new user
    if (newUserCheck == true) {
    this.ref
          .doc(uid)
          .set({
            id: firebaseUser.uid,
            username: firebaseUser.name,
            email: firebaseUser.email,
          })
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ChooseRoute')
  }
}
})
}
  // If login type is not success:
  (error => {   
    this.setState({loggedIn: "Login failed: log in again"})
    this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });

    });
}
```

Comment: Consider to focus on the main problem, it should be fine grained, instead of dumping your whole code to the comminity and trying to find the needle in the haystack. Do not let others to you're work as long as you want them to help you.

Comment: And this is why I don't use 'SO' much...as a relative newbie I have no idea where the problem is in this function, but I tried to be as specific as poss in the question - however, if you don't like my question, feel free to move on without responding....

Comment: Dive deeper into your error ouput. There are not any more information? Any reference, code line, module, what ever?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I stepped away for a bit...unfortunately there's no code line etc as the warning is just a 'yellowbox' warning so it's pretty indecipherable to me...and quite long, but it's here: https://gist.github.com/callyb/73084f43403b690d661be74a6a58186c

Comment: An update: I'm still stuck but I've tried putting the whole redirection code (everything after the FB log in code) into ComponentDidMount and it's definitely the onAuthStateChanged function that's messing up the navigation - any attempts to change screens or even set state inside the function gives error messages...I have no idea why at this stage....I'm now trying to check binding as an issue... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!!  3 days later - it was a binding issue - after several unsuccessful attempts to work out which were the right parts of the functions to bind I converted both 'auth().onAuthStateChanged' and 'documentSnapshot' into fat arrow functions and the errors are gone!!  Thank goodness for ES6...!  Hope this helps someone else down the line...